# adding <a> tag in div but href does not work

Tags: html, href

I have following html code but the TasksCount class does not show up as hyperlink. Any idea? I updated the anchor with the wording Link but still no good.

```
<div id="TaskNotification" style="display: inline!important;  float: left; border; 3px solid #8AC007;PADDING: 5px;"> 
<img id="NotificatioImg" class="n-img" "="" src="../SiteAssets/tasks_sm.png?rev=23" alt="Notification">
<div class="TasksCount">
    <a href="../pages/Tasks.aspx">Link </a> 
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
<style>

body {
    font-family:Calibri;
}
#customTaskNotification {
    position:relative;


}
.TasksCount {
    position:absolute;
    top: -.1px; 
    right:-.1px;
    padding:1px 2px 1px 2px;
    background-color:#ff0000; /* orange #ef8913* dark-pink #d06079 */
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.05em;
    width:50%;
    text-align: center;

    border-radius:50%!important;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 1px gray;
}

div.TasksCount:empty { 
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Here is the jQuery that populates TasksCount Div

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="_layouts/15/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var rowCount = $(".ms-WPBody tr").not(":has(th)").length;
        var x = $('.ms-WPBody tr td  a').html();
        if(x.indexOf("There are no items") !== -1){        
        rowCount = "";
        }
         $(".rowCount").text(rowCount);
         $(".TasksCount").text(rowCount);
    });     
</script>
```

Comment: because it has no content?

Comment: Because you populate TaskCount overwriting the link? - try `$(".TaskCount>a").text(rowCount)` instead

Comment: Perfect: It worked in first try. thanks you so much.

Comment: mplugjan: Please reply $(".TaskCount>a").text(rowCount) via answer so I can mark your reply as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you populate TaskCount overwriting the link? - try

```
$(".TaskCount>a").text(rowCount)
```

instead

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="TaskNotification" style="display: inline!important;  float: left; border; 3px solid #8AC007;PADDING: 5px;"> 
<img id="NotificatioImg" class="n-img" "=" src="../SiteAssets/tasks_sm.png?rev=23" alt="Notification">
<div class="TasksCount">
    <a href="../pages/Tasks.aspx">Link</a> 
</div>
</div>
```

The anchor tag has no text. Just put in some text.

*Not what you are looking for? Let me know :)*

Comment: I updated the html and attached the CSS in the original post. However the link does not get established.

Comment: @ShawnTorres the path is probably wrong. I have tested it. Check it out here :http://jsfiddle.net/28L3n3oz/

Comment: my bad. the links appears however, I am using a jQuery to populate TasksCount. I think I need to add href to TasksCount in jQuery. Any idea how to do that? I updated my post with jQuery

Comment: sure. I added to the original post.

Comment: @ShawnTorres sorry , cant help . I can suggest you something. Remove the jquery code from this post and ask it as another question

Comment: @ShawnTorres it would be great if you could mark this as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<img class="n-img" "="" src="../SiteAssets/tasks_sm.png?rev=23" alt="Notification">
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I fixed it but that's not the issue here.